# ¿Se puede programar cierto tiempo para que se ejecute un servicio automáticamente en c#?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

Quisiera que mi servicio se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, y quisiera que se ejecute cada hora para que pueda habilitar un botón en el front, pero, se podría programar el servicio para que se ejecute por si solo?, el servicio recibirá un parámetro id y lo tengo que almacenar en una variable par que se mantenga con el mismo usuario. El resultado para habilitar el botón es 1 y cero para deshabilitarlo. Adjunto el código del backend realizado en .net core.

```cs
public int habilitarBotonIngSal(int trab_id)
{
    DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Now;
    var horaSalActBoton = fechaActual.TimeOfDay;
    var verifIngreso = Convert.ToDateTime(_marcacionContext.Marcacion.Where(x => x.mar_id_trab.Equals(trab_id)).OrderByDescending(y => y.mar_fec).Select(a => a.mar_fec).FirstOrDefault());
    int activarBoton = 0;
    if (fechaActual < verifIngreso)
    {
        activarBoton = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        activarBoton = 0;
    }

    var verifSalida = _marcacionContext.Marcacion.Where(x => x.mar_id_trab.Equals(trab_id)).OrderByDescending(t => t.mar_fec).Select(a => new { fecha = a.mar_fec, tipo = a.mar_tip }).FirstOrDefault();
    var ConvActivarBotonSalida = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1990 13:00:00.0000000");
    var horaSalActBot = ConvActivarBotonSalida.TimeOfDay;
    DateTime fechaActual2 = DateTime.Today;

    if (verifSalida.tipo.Equals("I") && fechaActual2.Equals(Convert.ToDateTime(verifSalida.fecha)) && horaSalActBot <= horaSalActBoton)
    {
        activarBoton = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        activarBoton = 0;
    }

    return activarBoton;
}
```

Comment: La ejecución automatizada de servicios o scripts se llama **CRON Jobs**. Los _CRON Jobs_ son trabajos automatizados que ejecutan un script o archivo cada cierto tiempo. Es posible que necesites consultar a tu proveedor de alojamiento web o en la nube para poder saber si soportan los _CRON Jobs_ y cuáles son sus tarifas.

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez pero desde el código no se puede realizar?

Comment: En windows se llama tareas programadas (task scheduler). Anda al menú inicio y escribe "tareas programadas". Además yo he ocupado una librería (nuget) que se llama Quartz https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: ¿Y no es más sencillo que el front realice una llamada cada hora al back para actualizar el estado del botón? Porque con el resto de soluciones, a parte de utilizar alguna de las opciones que te dan o un BackgroundService, para notificárselo al front deberías implementar alguna forma de emitir notificaciones push, usando por ejemplo SignalR.